# Height of a cell according to height of the table

Tags: html, css, height

I have the following code :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Black Box -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Search Box -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>
            <table>
                <tr><td class='thead'>Statut</td></tr>
                <tr><td><!-- THE TD TO RESIZE --></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td class='thead'>Annonce</td></tr>
                <tr><td><!-- Don't Care --></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td class='thead'>Message</td></tr>
                <tr><td><!-- Don't Care --></td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It renders like this: http://imageshack.us/a/img689/3140/tbi4.png

But I would like the orange cell under "Statut" to fill the whole height of the containing TD. I tried to apply a height property to the table, the TR and the TD, but nothing happens, be it in HTML with height=... or in CSS with style='height: ...

Here's the render I'd like to have: http://imageshack.us/a/img560/3809/dy4w.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could argue that tables are not the best choice here, as they should only be used for tabular data, not for layout.

However, if you decide to go with tables, you should not nest them, but work with rowspan to achieve the deisred result. The HTML would look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Black Box -->noir</td>
        <td>
            <!-- Search Box -->cherche</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='titre'>Statut</td>
        <td class='titre'>Annonce</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='3'>lorem ipsum statut</td>
        <td>lorem ipsum annonce</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='titre'>Message</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lorem ipsum message</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This way you do not need to bother with heights in css (which can be a pain).

I set up a small example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/qJQdj/

Answer (score 0):

Try `height:100%;` to make it takes the total height.

Comment: I already tried to put this everywhere I could, but nothing did it.

Answer (score 0):

**changed code :**  convert your code to:

```
<table>

     <tr >
          <td class='thead' rowspan='2'>Statut</td>
           <td class='thead'>Message</td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td class='thead'>Message</td></tr>

</table>
```

it will give you what u want for sure

**EDIT:**  this is the concept of using rowspan.now you should use it to build your own webpage.there are few more cells as well in your code.you can do that using nested tables.my answer shows how to use rowspan properly

Answer (score 0):

Employing `min-height` will do the trick for you here if you are content aware of the table.

CSS

```
td[rowspan="2"] > table{
    min-height:80px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LWxK4/

Comment: I don't know the height the box will have in px, as the right side can be of any size. I tried applying a min-height: 100%; v=but it doesn't work.

Comment: do you mind javascript/jquery? few lines will let you keep your tables the way it is, and also maybe your hair.

Answer (score 0):

### If you really wanted nested tables...

You can force a nested table/table-cell to have a minimum height as follows:

Add a class `.statut-panel` to your inner table:

```
<table class="wrap">
    <tr>
        <td>Black Box</td>
        <td>Search Box</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>
            <table class="statut-panel">
                <tr>
                    <td class='thead'>Statut</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="full-size">
                    <td>THE TD TO RESIZE...</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table class="annonce-panel">
                <tr>
                    <td class='thead'>Annonce</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Don't Care</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class='thead'>Message</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Don't Care</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```css
table td {
    background-color: lightgray;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table.statut-panel {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 200px;
}
table.statut-panel .full-size td {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Give the inner table `.status-panel` a fixed height, say 200px.  CSS will treat this as a minimum height so you won't get into any overflow issues as the table content expands.

For the table cell that you want to expand, `table.statut-panel .full-size td`, simply set the height to 100%, and it will expand in height to at least 200px (or whatever is a good minimum height).

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7L3Bc/